# Putting everything on one line with unordered list

Tags: html, css, css-float, html-lists

It seems like a simple problem but whatever i did i couldn't solve it. I post a link about what i am talking. http://www.olmasigereken.com/demo/?view=listen&artist=ibrahim+ferrer&track=dos+gardenias
If you look at page codes you will see that order of items is ***red arrow artistname dash(-) trackname twitter and facebook links***. However the output is not like that. I want to put everything on one line with correct order which is ***red image artistname dash trackname twitter and facebook links***.

Note: When you click it if you don't see anything please refresh the page.

```
                          <li>
                            <img src="img/track_arrow.gif" alt="" />
                            <div class="singer">
                                <a href="#"><?php echo $a[artistname]?></a> 
                            </div>                                                             
                            -
                            <div class="song">
                                <a href="#"><?php echo $a[trackname]?></a> 
                            </div>

                            <div class="fav">
                                <a target="_blank" href="#" /><img src="img/twit.gif" alt="share on twitter" /></a>
                                <a target="_blank" href="#"> <img src="img/face.gif" alt="share on facebook" /> </a> 
                            </div>
                            <br />
                        </li>
```

Comment: It is unnecessary. You can right click the page.

Comment: it is necessary. If you are not going to  put the effort in to as a clear question, and make the life easier for people answering, then you are not going to get much of an effort to answer.

Comment: My friend, i don't want to argue but if your effort understanding is copying the source code and pasting it here, there is wrong with your effort understanding.

Comment: Thanks, i'll keep it in my mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The floating left of links inside is causing conflict. If you remove the `float: left` as seen in the following screenshot, I think you will get what you want...

[image: incorrect float]

[image: result]

Answer (score 1):

You need to set some css propertys like

```
.ikinciSol ul li {
widht: 375px;
}

.fav{
float: right;
}
```

Hope this may helpful to you.

Comment: Thank you. It just put fb and twitter link on same line but still dash and image are in wrong places.

Comment: As you see in code arrow image is first item. But when i apply your code image still is behind the trackname.

Answer (score 0):

try this to put each element between li balises and use the css attributewith ul element: list-style-type:none;

Comment: I put every element between li balises and use 'list-style-type:none;' but it does not work.